# Jquery - Array of all days in a year

Tags: jquery, date, plugins

I'm looking for an easy way to get a string array of all the dates in a given year. Something like:

```
function getDates( year ) {

    // algorithm...

    return dates;

}
```

which returns an array like:

```
    getDates( 2013 ) = {"01/01/2013", "01/02/2013", ... , "12/31/2013"}
```

There are leap years, and such, so I'd rather not recreate the wheel by coding this myself, so:
**Question:** Are there any JavaScript plugins that can accomplish this?

I am aware of Jquery Datepicker, but after reading the documentation, I don't think it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date.prototype.getDaysInMonth = function(month){
    var date = new Date(this.getFullYear(), month, 1);
    var days = [];
    while (date.getMonth() === month) {
        days.push(new Date(date));
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    return days;
};


function getDays(date){

    var result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < 12; i++){
        var r = date.getDaysInMonth(i);

        $.each(r, function(k, v){
            var formatted = v.getDate() + 
               '/' + (v.getMonth() +1) + '/' + v.getFullYear();
            result.push(formatted);
        });
    }

    return result;
}

console.log(getDays(new Date()));
```

Result:

```
["1/1/2013", "2/1/2013", "3/1/2013", "4/1/2013"..."]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nkMLM/3/

Answer (score 3):

It can be as simple as

```
var date = new Date(2013, 0, 1);
var end =  new Date(date);
end.setFullYear(end.getFullYear() + 1);
var array = [];
while(date < end){
    array.push(date);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1)
}
```

Comment: Clean Approach! **Note** - `array.push(date)` will just push a reference to the date (which is subsequently updated each loop) so you should update to `array.push(new Date(start))` - if you console log the array currently, it'll just be 365 array values repeating `2014/01/01`